# Output caching in web.config under SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, caching

I am trying to configure output caching on a web application that runs under SharePoint Foundation 2010. I understand from other posts that this cannot be done in SP Foundation, and that it has to be done at the IIS level.

I have modified the web.config file to include a caching profile for the .aspx file I am trying to cache, but the output is still not cached.

Request tracing indicates a OUTPUT_CACHE_DISABLED entry.
 [image: IIS tracing of request]

So even though it appears that IIS picks the cache policy (i.e. for time) and duration (i.e. 10 min) from the web.config file, the output is still not cached.

I have been using similar web.config changes in web sites that did not fall under SharePoint, and found no such issue. So I suspect that SP Foundation still somehow imposes disabling of output caching.

Is that so, and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Main reason output cache or object cache does not work with SharePoint foundation is SharePoint Publishing features. In SharePoint foundation, we don't have publishing feature that's why this cache not works (it does not work with collaboration site).

I am not sure, how we can handle this via asp.net.